# How can I hide menu from drawer navigation in react native base on database user permission?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a project in react native using expo.
I have a switch navigation for login. After login I have  a drawer navigation that contains separate stack navigation. For each screen I want to hide few menus from drawer navigation based on user permissions as the application will be used by admin, employee, manager etc.

Or is there any other way to create a dynamic drawer navigation based on my requirement with menu fetched from database according to user permission?

Drawer navigation should be rendered based on user type after login.

Here is my code snippet for drawer navigation:

```js
const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: createStackNavigator({
      HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
          return {
            title: "Dashboard",
            headerLeft: (
              <Ionicons
                name="md-menu"
                size={32}
                color="white"
                style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}
                onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
              />
            ),
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#B00020"
            },
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: "bold"
            }
          };
        }
      }
    }),
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      drawerLabel: "Dashboard",
      drawerIcon: () => <Ionicons name="md-home" size={28} color="#B00020" />
    })
  },
  UserlistDetails: {
    name: UserlistDetails,
    screen: createStackNavigator({
      UserlistDetails: {
        screen: UserlistDetails,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
          return {
            title: "User Accnt Details",
            headerLeft: (
              <Ionicons
                name="md-menu"
                size={32}
                color="white"
                style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}
                onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
              />
            ),
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#B00020"
            },
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: "bold"
            }
          };
        }
      },
      CreateNewUser: {
        screen: CreateNewUser,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
          return {
            title: "Create New User",
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#B00020" },
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: "bold" }
          };
        }
      }
    }),
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      drawerLabel: "User Accnt Details",
      drawerIcon: () => <Ionicons name="md-person" size={28} color="#B00020" />
    })
  }
});

const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
  { Dashboard: DrawerNav },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return { header: null };
    }
  }
);

const Navigation = createAppContainer(StackNav);

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = { header: null };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Navigation />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the react navigation docs, it states that one limitation is the lack of ability to have dynamic routes. All routes have to be static and defined at the beginning. See more here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/limitations.html#targetText=Dynamic%20routes&targetText=React%20Navigation%20does%20not%20currently,can%20do%20this%20using%20params.